# Replace KDE Wallet with Password Manager like Lockwise

Tags: kde, password, gnome-keyring, kwallet

I recently started using Lockwise as Password Manager for my Firefox and Android. Now the only Passwords I still need to enter are the ones outside of my Browser on my Desktop. Is there any way to setup Lockwise (or other Password Managers in General) instead of KDE Wallet as Keyring system? So far, I've only had Problems with KDE Wallet system - the only thing it seems to do correctly are WiFi Passwords. There are quite a few other applications where I should enter a password, and while sometimes KDE Wallet knows it's being requested (for many programs it doesn't), it never actually enters passwords.

Is there generally in Unix (Kubuntu 20.04 (KDE) in my case) the possibility to use Password-Managers for applications, like it's possible in Android? (If not, why not? Is there a technical reason why it's not possible or is that simply not done yet because nobody found the time to do it?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_password_managers#Comparison I assume you mainly want browser integration? The most lightweight (and CLI-only) option would be `pass`, but you'll need a plugin for browser support.

Comment: I'm not sure if integrating password managers with apps is worth it.  I personally use my own password manager [nsapass](https://github.com/Al-Caveman/nsapass) which runs in terminal, and allows me to paste usernames/passwords in any window I want with keyboard shortcuts (e.g. `nsa u` to let it type the username, and `nsa p` to let it type the password; of course, after `nsa get ...` to retrieve the specific entry).

Comment: @Fiximan - actually no, I want everything besides browser. Lockwise works perfectly for Browsers, I am just annoyed that other applications don't work that conveniently